# How to perform simple calculations with military time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a problem in an asp.net mvc application where I'll need to take a military time as a string something like "2200" and then I'll take a duration time as a double that could be something like 3.5 standing for 3 and a half hours.

I will then need to determine if the starting time and the duration are greater than or equal to "2400" meaning that the duration goes into the next day.

I'm not sure how to go about this, if there's a header I need to include for doing simple addition with military time. I know I could convert the string to an int, however integers are decimal and time is not, so I don't see how that could work.

Any help is appreciated, thanks for taking the time to ready my question!

Comment: What code do you have thus far?

Comment: Convert all absolute times into DateTime using DateTime.Parse, and convert all relative times into TimeSpan using TimeSpan.Parse. Then use methods and properties on those objects to do the calculations. You can then format the result as military time, or in any other format that's appropriate. 2200 hours and 10 pm are the same time of day, hence the DateTime value: A store that closes at 10 pm won't be open if you show up in uniform. You're just displaying it in a string differently.

Comment: @EdPlunkett That's what I was looking for, thanks! I struggled to find stuff about this on google, and couldn't find similar questions on stack overflow, thank you

Comment: As @EdPlunkett says, `DateTime` and `TimeSpan` will be your friends (particularly the latter).  In particular, a `TimeSpan` can represent a time of day (it's just the time span from midnight to a particular time).  Parse "2200" into a TimeSpan.  Then create a second one to represent three and a half (there are static factory methods for that kind of thing).  Adding two time spans together will give you another timespan.  Then you can check to see if it's greater than 24 hours

Comment: Remember that these types of calculations are error prone or even ill-defined on the day that daylight savings time is starting or ending. The framework will not handle this for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
//define military time format string 
string _format = "HHmm";
//your time
string time = "2200";
//parse string to DateTime using defined format
DateTime normalTime = DateTime.ParseExact(time, _format, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
//add hours to DateTime variable
DateTime newTime = normalTime.AddHours(3.5);
//convert DateTime to military time string using defined format string
string newTimeText = newTime.ToString(_format);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the same thing just using `TimeSpan`s:

```
 var milTime = "2200";
 TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.ParseExact(milTime, "hhmm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
 TimeSpan offset = new TimeSpan(3, 30, 0);    //represents 3.5 hours
 TimeSpan result = time + offset;
 bool exceedsOneDay = result.Days >= 1;
```

The result of the addition is a `TimeSpan` of 1 day, 0 hours and 30 minutes.

If you are tied to "3.5" as a method of describing your offset, you could  change the `offset` declaration and initialization to:

```
 TimeSpan offset = TimeSpan.FromHours(3.5);
```

and you get the same result.

Comment: If you use `DateTime` instead of `TimeSpan` you simplify things a lot and there is no need for extra time calculation nor adding offsets.

Comment: TimeSpan.FromHours(3.5) would be cleaner

Comment: @JonasHøgh: Agreed.  Updating now.  Thanks!!

Comment: @Matt: The method is just about the same (parse the string, add an offset, check the result).  The advantage of TimeSpan over DateTime is that fundamentally, a DateTime represents, well, a date and a time.  A TimeSpan is a time-only thing (with no complications coming from Date-ness).  To me (at least), working in the TimeSpan domain is closer to the problem domain.  To each their own.